# What possible causes are there to "Item has already been added...Oracle.DataAccess"?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, custom-type

I'm attempting to call an Oracle sproc via Oracle.DataAccess.Client.  The actual exec call produces this error:

```
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Oracle.DataAccess,
Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'  Key
being added: 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'
```

Stack trace:

```
at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
```

I'm at a loss as to where to start diagnosing this problem; there's no hash table in my code, and the stack trace doesn't tell me where in framework or library code the problem is occurring.  Googling has produced nothing that seems to be relevant.  I can query data just fine, and I can ran another sproc succesfully.  I can run this sproc directly in SQL Developer without a problem, using the same creds and arguments.

I had been getting a similar error message referring to a general utility library, which was not actually used.  Removing the reference left me with the above `Oracle.DataAccess` error.

Here's the code; this is just casual testing, thus the lack of error handling.

```
var  conn = new OracleConnection("<conn string>");  conn.Open();

var  cmd = new OracleCommand("MySchema.MySproc", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

var  param = new OracleParameter("ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Input);
param.Value = 1234;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
// Several more IN params; there are no name collisions

param = new OracleParameter("NumUpdatesMade", OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param = new OracleParameter("TypeList", OracleDbType.Array, ParameterDirection.Input);
param.UdtTypeName = "MySchema.SimpleVARRAYCustomType";
param.Value       = new [] { "A", "B" };
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // Error thrown here
Console.Out.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["NumUpdatesMade"]);
```

I've not used Oracle custom types before, and the other sproc which I've successfully tested does not have a custom type.  However, if it was the problem, I'd expect to see some hint to that effect in the error message.

If it's relevant, here's the definition for the custom type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MySchema.SimpleVARRAYCustomType AS VARRAY(100) OF VARCHAR2(5);
```

Comment: Did you try using the code generation wizard for MySchema.SimpleVARRAYCustomType? It is part of the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio. http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/appdev/dotnet/userdefinedtypes/index.html

Comment: In general I would advise NOT using a VARRAY when an associative array can be used instead for performance and ease of use considerations. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17odp-093600.html

Comment: @ChristianShay: No, though I'd rather not get too deep into the library for this simple task.  What would be the advantage of an assoc array when the incoming data is not keyed?  VARRAY appears to be the simplest possible collection, given that the alternative would be a scalar containing a CSV.

Comment: I mentioned the code generation wizard as a sanity check. Make sure it works with that and then compare it's code to what you are using. I think you will find that associative arrays are simpler to code. As for assoc arrays, it's a performance consideration. Associative arrays are quite a but faster and VARRAYs (and UDTs in general) can have performance issues. If you aren't worried too much about performance, then go for which ever you like better. You could also use a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

I have just started getting he same error, but for when enqueueing a message with a UDT.  My class that was defined for the UDT was missing a constructor. I think you need a class generated for your UDT MySchema.SimpleVARRAYCustomType, to instantiate an object of that class with your values, and to assign that to param.Value.